# Django Template: If Variable doesn't exist do some stuff

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using the following Django template code which is working perfectly:

```
        {% for details in teamsremaining %}
          <tr>
            <TD class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" ><img src="/static/straightred/images/smalllogo/{{details.teamname}}SmallLogo.svg" alt="" width="22" height="22"/>&nbsp;{{details.teamname}}</TD>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

However, on some occasions there will be NO teams remaining so the for loop will not run.  If this is the case I would like to have:

```
<tr>
  <TD class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" >NO TEAMS REMAINING.</TD>
</tr>
```

I thought I could just use the {% if NOT teamsremaining } code here {% endif %} but had no joy.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`for ... empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) template tag:

```
   {% for details in teamsremaining %}
      <tr>
        <TD class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" ><img src="/static/straightred/images/smalllogo/{{details.teamname}}SmallLogo.svg" alt="" width="22" height="22"/>&nbsp;{{details.teamname}}</TD>
      </tr>
    {% empty %}
       <tr>
          <TD class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" >NO TEAMS REMAINING.</TD>
       </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have not seen that before!  Many thanks for a swift response.